# How to output javascript and make sleep or wait work in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a foreach loop, which uses an array of variables to produce dynamic javascript with ajax calls. Let's say I have an array of 10 variables and need to create 10 different JS scripts. Those scripts shouldn't be executed at once, they should have at least 1-2 seconds delay. However, I can't make that work with sleep or wait. Here is my code:

```
<?php
foreach ($one as $two) {
$somevariable = $two['sth'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var somevariable = <?php echo json_encode($somevariable); ?>;
  // JS code with ajax call, using somevariable
});
</script>

<?php
sleep(2); // doesn't work, everything is executed at once
wait(2); // doesn't work, everything is executed at once
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Would the code work if I echo the script? I'd like to avoid that, since JS code is quite long and complex.

Comment: Since your `sleep()` is in PHP, the only thing that happens is that it will take longer for the script to be sent to the client. PHP is parsed on the server, when it's all done, it's sent to the client where the javascript gets parsed.

Comment: why not do it in reverse, make the interval xmlhttprequest instead

Comment: What you should to is looking into the `setTimeout()`-function i javascript. Read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Why not make a promise callback chain?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Wouldn't it then also send multiple scripts at once and each one of them would wait for n seconds?

Comment: Your server will return everything in one go. You can in your loop just add on how many extra milliseconds you want to wait between the scripts in every iteration in your loop: `timeout += 1000; setTimeout(function(){ //.. do stuff}, timeout)` or something like that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That does make sense. I could check iteration's n and then use something like n+1000ms for the timeout. If you want, you can add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this: First, form a javascript array from your php code.

```
<?php
foreach ($one as $two) {
    $somevariable[] = "'".json_encode($two['sth'])."'";
}
$jsArray = '['.implode(',',$somevariable).']';
?>
```

Then pass the array to your javascript and run a loop with a 2 sec interval in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var somevariablearray = <?php echo $jsArray; ?>;
  var ln = somevariablearray.length();
  for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
      var somevariable = somevariablearray[i];
      setTimeout(function(){
          console.log("Wait 2 sec before next call");
      }, 2000);
      // JS code with ajax call, using somevariable
  }
});
</script>
```

The code is not tested and might not work as expected, but, just to give you a general idea.